# Why is the "Price and TIme" Table header not covering the division fully

Tags: html

I have an issue with my HTML code, I'm not able to figure out why the "Price and TIme" Table header is not covering the division fully.

Can someone help me in how to resolve this code im pretty sure my code is buggy, but Im not sure where the bug is.

Here is my HTML code.

```html
<table cellspacing="0" summary="Moroccan oil Treatment">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price and Time <span style="padding-right:20px"> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Moroccan Head Therapy & Hair Wash (45 Min)<br> Enjoy a stimulating Head Therapy with Organic Oils. Moroccan oil moisture repair shampoo, which is Sulface-Phosphate and Paraben Free, gently and effectively removes dirt from scalp and hair. It nourishes
      and revives weak and damaged hair, leaving it manageable and strong. It is rich in antioxidant Argan oil, Keratin and Fatty acids</td>
    <td>Men <br><br> 1025/-</td>
    <td> Ladies <br> Short <br> 750/-</td>
    <td><br> Medium <br> 1325/-</td>
    <td><br> Long <br> 1525/-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Moroccan Oil Hair Styling / Blow Dry (45 Min)<br> This Moroccan journey starts with a Shampoo and Conditioner. Your hair is then Hyderated, Conditioned and Styled using products that fight Frizz and add definition while giving a Soft Hold to Blow-Dry.</td>
    <td>Men <br><br> 700/-</td>
    <td> Ladies <br> Medium <br> 825/-</td>
    <td><br> Long <br> 1320/-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Moroccan Oil Hydrating / Restorative Hair Spa (60 Min)<br> A High-Performance Formula which is rich in Aryan Oil and Protien helps fortify and Re-construct hair that has been damaged by chemical treatments and heat styling. It leaves your hair more Beautiful than before.</td>
    <td>Men <br><br> 825/-</td>
    <td> Ladies <br> Short <br> 1050/-</td>
    <td><br> Medium <br> 1250/-</td>
    <td><br> Long <br> 1600/-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Here is the picture and my code snippet]

Answer (score 0):

You have a weird unclosed `span` here `<th>Price and Time <span style="padding-right:20px"> </th>` and you need a colspan on it

```
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th colspan="4" >Price and Time</th>
</tr>
```

I would also use thead and tbody and add a border to separate the entries

```css
tr td { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<table summary="Moroccan oil Treatment">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="4">Price and Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Moroccan Head Therapy & Hair Wash (45 Min)<br> Enjoy a stimulating Head Therapy with Organic Oils. Moroccan oil moisture repair shampoo, which is Sulface-Phosphate and Paraben Free, gently and effectively removes dirt from scalp and hair. It nourishes
        and revives weak and damaged hair, leaving it manageable and strong. It is rich in antioxidant Argan oil, Keratin and Fatty acids</td>
      <td>Men<br><br> 1025/-</td>
      <td> Ladies<br> Short<br> 750/-</td>
      <td><br> Medium<br> 1325/-</td>
      <td><br> Long<br> 1525/-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Moroccan Oil Hair Styling / Blow Dry (45 Min)<br> This Moroccan journey starts with a Shampoo and Conditioner. Your hair is then Hyderated, Conditioned and Styled using products that fight Frizz and add definition while giving a Soft Hold to Blow-Dry.</td>
      <td>Men<br><br> 700/-</td>
      <td> Ladies<br> Medium<br> 825/-</td>
      <td><br> Long<br> 1320/-</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Moroccan Oil Hydrating / Restorative Hair Spa (60 Min)<br> A High-Performance Formula which is rich in Aryan Oil and Protien helps fortify and Re-construct hair that has been damaged by chemical treatments and heat styling. It leaves your hair more
        Beautiful than before.</td>
      <td>Men<br><br> 825/-</td>
      <td> Ladies<br> Short<br> 1050/-</td>
      <td><br> Medium<br> 1250/-</td>
      <td><br> Long<br> 1600/-</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```